# SQL query - need to add most recent date

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I have two tables one is 'Property' has a primary key ID with numbers 1-9 and the other ('Viewings') has a a field which uses one of the ID numbers in each record- some numbers might be used more than once, e.g.  4 might be in two records. In viewing there is also a date field for each record.

I have a query which counts the number of times a value occurs in the viewings table and returns a datasheet with the ID from the Property table and how many times that ID occurs in the field in the Viewings table.

What I am trying to do now is to append the date for each of the rows. The difficult part is that since some records will have number 4 twice for example, there will be two different dates. I want to be able to select the most recent date and make it appear as the third column in my query.

I have this so far to count the ID's, but I'm trying to add the date as well:

```
SELECT Property.ID,
Count(Viewings.Property_Viewed) AS ViewingCount
FROM Property LEFT JOIN Viewings ON Property.ID = Viewings.Property_Viewed
GROUP BY Property.ID;
```

Here's my attempt at adding the date- which is not complete:

```
SELECT Property.ID, Viewings.Viewing_Date,
Count(Viewings.Property_Viewed) AS ViewingCount,
MAX(Viewings.Viewing_Date) AS Vdate
FROM Property LEFT JOIN Viewings ON Property.ID = Viewings.Property_Viewed
GROUP BY Property.ID;
```

Comment: Show us with an example of where your second query fails.

Comment: @user2989408 I don't know how to link the Date with the rest of the query. Like I have the Proporty.ID linked with the Viewings.Propoerty_Viewed matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is you only need remove `Viewings.Viewing_Date` from the `SELECT` clause in order to get the result you want.

```sql
SELECT
    Property.ID, 
    Count(Viewings.Property_Viewed) AS ViewingCount,
    MAX(Viewings.Viewing_Date) AS Vdate
FROM
    Property
    LEFT JOIN Viewings
    ON Property.ID = Viewings.Property_Viewed
GROUP BY Property.ID;
```

That result set should include a row for each `Property.ID` with the count of viewings for that property and the date of the most recent viewing.  The date column will contain null for any properties not found in the `Viewings` table.

The problem with `Viewings.Viewing_Date` in the `SELECT` clause is it is neither ...

1. a field expression based on an aggregate function (count, min, max, etc.)
2. included in the `GROUP BY` clause

Access generally complains when it encounters a field expression which doesn't satisfy either of those conditions.

Comment: WOW it was that simple..? haha Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend actually building out each query separately and then join each back to the Property Table.

So you would do something like:

```
SELECT 
    P.Id AS PropertyId
    VC.ViewingCount,
    VD.LastViewing
FROM Property P
LEFT JOIN
( 
    SELECT 
        Property_Viewed AS PropertyId
        Count(Viewings.Property_Viewed) AS ViewingCount 
    FROM Viewings
    GROUP BY Property_Viewed
) AS VC ON P.Id = VC.PropertyId
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        Property_Viewed AS PropertyId
        MAX(Viewings.Viewing_Date) AS LastViewing
    FROM Viewings
    GROUP BY Property_Viewed
) AS VD ON P.Id = VD.PropertyId
```